# Android - NullPOinterException on my activity

Tags: android

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

I have one activity called `LogInActivity` which is the `MainActivity`

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
  }

  public void checkLogin(View view){
    final String emailText = email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String passwordTex = password.getText().toString().trim();
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOGIN_URL, successListener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", emailText);
                params.put("password", passwordTex);
                return params;
            }
        };

        ReqQueue.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
```

Removed `Listener functions` for  simplicity.

My `ReQueue` class is as follows

```
public class ReqQueue extends Application{
    private static ReqQueue instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized ReqQueue getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(requestQueue == null){
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return  requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req){
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    }
```

If I execute the code I get `NullPointeRException`. I found the position where it occurs. It occurs at this line `ReqQueue.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(req);` of login activity.

Instance is null. But I create the instance at onCreate method as mentioned in the tutorial. But that oncreate method never called.

If I do all the queue activities in my activity clss itself it works. How do I solve it?

**Stack Error**

> 04-24 16:24:39.254 10272-10272/com.gopsab.loginsystem
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.gopsab.loginsystem, PID: 10272
>                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'com.android.volley.RequestQueue
>   com.gopsab.utils.ReqQueue.getRequestQueue()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                               at
>   com.gopsab.loginsystem.LoginActivity.checkLogin(LoginActivity.java:73)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: What is there to close on? It's your fault your skipped something in the tutorial. NullPointers are commonly downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: you did not add an `android:name` attribute to the `<application>` element of your manifest, pointing at `com.gopsab.utils.ReqQueue`. As a result, `onCreate()` was never called, and `instance` is still `null`.

Comment: Oh My God.I thought `name` is for just naming. Let me try this Sir

Comment: @GopsAB: `android:label` is for user-visible display names. `android:name` is for identifying the Java class for that particular element. `<application>` does not *need* `android:name`, but then it will just use `android.app.Application`, not your custom `Application` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your activity context in ReqQueue via Constructor, then it will not give this exception. DOn't use getApplicationContext() at this stage.